# Apache Camel dataFormat

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

Im using Camel to handle requests from a webservice and route those request to somewhere else (i will send them to RabbitMQ, but this is not relevant for my question).

Im using the standard Dataformat in camel-cxf endpoint which is POJO, but when i receive the packet in the camel route, im getting something that im not expecting.

Let me show you what i have right now, and i hope someone can point me in the right direction :)

Im using SOAPUI to send the request to the webservice:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:es:tf:mm:types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:PromoEvent>
         <urn:id>601234567</urn:id>
         <urn:text>qwerty</urn:text>
         <urn:date>01012001</urn:date>
      </urn:PromoEvent>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now, I have the following cxf endpoint bean definition in my camel-context.xml file, which by default, uses the POJO dataformat:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="Promo"
address="/Promo"
serviceClass="es.tf.mm.mmPortType"/>
```

And finally, i defined a camel route where im printing some logs and following you can see the results:

```
<route id="fromMySOAPws" autoStartup="true">
    <from uri="cxf:bean:Promo"/>
    <log message="Body: ${body}"/>
    <log message="Body in: ${in.body}"/>
    <log message="Body 0: ${in.body[0]}"/>
    <log message="Body 1: ${in.body[1}"/>
    <log message="Body 2: ${in.body[2]}"/>
    <log message="Body 3: ${in.body[3]}"/>

    <transform>
           <simple>${in.body[0]}</simple>
    </transform>

    <unmarshal ref="jaxbWsDf"/>
    <process ref="PromoProcessRequest"/>

    <to uri="rabbitmq://rabbitmqhostname:5672/exchange_name?connectionFactory=#customConnectionFactory&amp;autoDelete=false"/>
    <bean ref="PromoResponse" method="generateResponse(0,&quot;event published in rabbitmq&quot;)"/>

</route>
```

Here you can see the PromoProcessRequest Java class:

```
public class PromoProcessRequest implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        EventPromoType request = (EventPromoType)exchange.getIn().getBody();

        Map<String, Object> eventFields = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

        eventFields.put("id", request.getId());
        eventFields.put("text", request.getText());
        eventFields.put("date", request.getDate());

        exchange.getOut().setBody(eventFields);
    }   
}
```

Results:

```
Body: qwerty
Body in: qwerty
Body 0: javax.xml.ws.Holder@6ecf43c8
Body 1: qwerty
Body 2: 1012001
Body 3:
```

Thank you all in advance :)

@EDIT:

As Souciance correctly asked, what is unexpected for me, is to have just one of the fields (text:'qwerty') as the whole {body} of the request.

Since im using the standard POJO dataFormat, i need to call a process before Camel sends the message to rabbit and create a JSON with all the fields.

Im updating the code to show you the whole Camel route and also to include the process method which is where im having the issues, since im trying to cast the body of the request.

Hope this clarifies everything a little bit, but ofc, feel free to ask for more details if needed.

@EDIT2:

As fiw asked, here is the jaxbWsDf definition which is declared inside the camelContext tag:

```
<dataFormats>
            <jaxb id="jaxbWsDf" prettyPrint="true" contextPath="es.tf.mm.types"/>
</dataFormats>
```

Also i would like to replicate here out my answer to the fiw second comment. When i compile the wsdl, in the auto-generated Java class, i cant see the @XmlRootElement and i think this is because the wsdl schema is declared in a external .xsd file. Am i right? Any other idea of why that XmlRootElement does not appear after compiling my webservice?

Thanks again!

Comment: You haven't written what part of the result is unexpected to you.

Comment: You're right, just edited the question to include more info. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you show the definition of your "jaxbWsDf" data format?

Comment: Also do you have a PromoEvent java class annotated with @XmlRootElement? You also might have to strip the SOAP stuff by using .xpath() DSL in your camel route and then you unmarshal it? Ideally you wouldn't have to do that because the cxf component, i thought, would sort it for you...

Comment: fiw, i think you've nailed it. I have a former example of the same architecture but with a simpler wsdl, checking the java class u mention, I can see that XmlRootElement, but in the current version, the wsdl have the elements defined in a external xsd file, and the java class generated does not contain that definition. Now the question would be, how should i modify the wsdl/xsd in order to have the XmlRootElement included in the Java class.

Comment: Excellent, we're closer then, what are you using to generate your java classes from your wsdl? There may be some configuration you need or namespace issue to make sure it generates properly from an external file, the first thing to try would be to put the schema inline and see if it generates properly and can unmarshal and then you can see how to make the schema external to the wsdl once you know the inline schema works.